# Whitespace concatenation in Bash

Tags: bash, whitespace, concatenation

The problem is simple.

```
for i in `seq $begin $progress_length` ; do
  progress_bar=$progress_bar'#'
done

for i in `seq $middle $end` ; do
  empty_space=$empty_space' '
done
```

I need `empty_space` to position content after the progress bar. I've expected that it will be string of x whitespaces. But finally string is empty. How may I create string of x whitespaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem may be because `$empty_space` has only spaces. Then, to output them you have to surround it in double quotes:

```
echo "${empty_space}some_other_thing"
```

You can try more interesting output with `printf` for example to obtain several spaces. For instance, to write 20 spaces:

```
v=`printf '%20s' ' '`
```

Comment: .. and the progress-bar `#` can _also_ be written with the `printf(1)`, probably simplifying both routines.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I tried "${empty_space} " before, but It doesn't works. Event empty_space=`printf '%20s' ' '` doesn't works :(. Bash is weird.

Comment: @ciembor: What do you mean, `empty_space="${empty_space} "` doesn't work? It appends a space to `empty_space`. How are you checking the value later? Presumably by printing it to your screen? Are you quoting it then? That is, you need to do `echo "[${progress_bar}${empty_space}]"`, not `echo [${progress_bar}${empty_space}]`.

Comment: I noticed, that bash removes all whitespaces from string edges. Even if string is not empty.

Comment: @Jefromi - I print it: `printf %s '['$progress_bar$empty_space']'`

Comment: @ciembor: Look back at my previous comment then. You're unnecessarily quoting the brackets, and you're not quoting the variables. The variables need to be surrounded with double quotes to protect the spaces. Otherwise, that's parsed as two arguments: `[######` and `]`. Spaces separate arguments. (And printf is probably superfluous if the format string is just `%s`.)

Comment: This answer is wrong. Expansion will not occur as described, and the outer quotes are not necessary. If `A=" "`, then after `B=$A`, `B` will equal `$A`, it will not be "empty." The assignment `B=$A` never needs quotes.

Comment: @Idelic: I think you missed the added space *within* the quotes. Of course it is not `B=$A`, but `B="$A "` (contents of `$A` plus space), which is perfectly legal, and more importantly, it is a correct answer, so maybe you missed something in your comment?

Comment: @Diego: I didn't miss them. The point is that the assignment `B=$A' '` is exactly the same as `B="$A "`. You say (or I understood that you said) that `B=$A' '` gets expanded into `B= ' '`, emptying the value of B. That's wrong. Just try it in your shell and see.

Comment: @Idelic, you're right. I'm correcting the answer. Maybe then the original problem is that the OP didn't used quotes when printing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The strings can be created using parameter substitution.
The substitution ${str:offset:length} returns a substring of str :

```
space80='                                                                                '
hash80='################################################################################'

progress_bar=${hash80:0:$progress_length-$begin+1}
empty_space=${space80:0:$end-$middle+1}

echo -n "$empty_space$progress_bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem as I had exactly the same.

My solution was to concatenate a temporary character instead of a whitespace, say for example `☼`, and then, at the end, replace all their occurences with `sed` by a whitespace :

```
echo $myString | sed 's/☼/ /g'
```

I hope it will help you !